# Can angular-cli remove unused css?

Tags: css, webpack, minify, angular-cli, angular2-aot

so far the smallest bundle I can create with angular cli is by running

> ng build --aot true -prod

I was wondering if the build process also removes unused css classes e.g. from bootstrap?

If not how can I add libraries like purifycss to it?

**EDIT April 2018**

I still did not find any satisfying solution to his problem, especially one that is compatible with the lazy loading modules with angular...

Cheers

Comment: Have you managed to find an answer to this? Currently having the same issue. I would like to either use PurifyCss or UnCss

Comment: I added a Feature Request for this.  Please vote for the issue.  Since Angular will add state dependent classes to element at runtime, it's tricky to use automation at the moment.  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24851

Answer (score 11):

I did some research recently about this, but I could not find any really safe way of how to remove unused CSS. However I came across some tools which would help you detect dead-code in VS Code. There is an [extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rcore.rcore-unused-css-classes#review-details) which is not perfect but looks promising. Also I did some investigation of how to remove unused Angular Material CSS (if you use it) and created a video about it. You can [check this out here](https://youtu.be/1rwRovyQGuo).

But at least now (in 2020) there is no any reliable way to achieve what you want and see also an [answer from Angular Core Team member about this topic](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9650#issuecomment-448724659)

Comment: What about using [ngx-unused-css](https://github.com/ivanblazevic/ngx-unused-css) to detect unused properties ? it is using [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/) behind the hood.

Comment: @FlavienVolken Well, it does extra improvements comparing to PurgeCSS but still... There is a statement from ngx-unused-css docs: "it finds all .html files inside the project and then pairs it with their styling files; e.g. app.component.html > app.component.scss", so it means, that *.ts files will be ignored but we can set css classes with Renderer as example, which means that the CSS class will be considered as unused when actually it is not true. So that's why I would not consider it as a 'safe' solutions, especially for medium and big projects  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
module.export={
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css'),
    // Make sure this is after ExtractTextPlugin!
    new PurifyCSSPlugin({
      // Give paths to parse for rules. These should be absolute!
      paths: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'app/*.html')),
    })
  ]

};
```

install purifycss webpack first

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web pack then you can do it as:-

First, install purifycss-webpackusing `npm i -D purifycss-webpack`

```
module.export={
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css'),
    // Make sure this is after ExtractTextPlugin!
    new PurifyCSSPlugin({
      // Give paths to parse for rules. These should be absolute!
      paths: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'app/*.html')),
    })
  ]

};
```

Visit the link below for the detailed understanding.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack

Comment: webpack is not exposed in angular-cli sadly

Comment: @DaveAhern Try `ng eject`. If you want more control over the webpack process, that's the way to do it. Read more here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Most of the styles are being removed. I supposed the plugin is checking against the index.html (it's empty, all the html will inject by angular) . Did any one find a solution?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack

Comment: there is prob;em with this solution, if you sue angular-material these days, its styling will be killed by purifycss, I established a site one firebase, the nav tab style is totally gone

Answer (score 0):

If you are ejected, i.e. [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject). Then you can customize the webpack build to do most anything.  I have a couple options turned on to minimize styles as part of the build with `minifyCSS` in two of the plugins.

1. LoaderOptionsPlugin

   ```
   new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
     "sourceMap": false,
     "options": {
       "html-minifier-loader": {
           "removeComments": true,
           "collapseWhitespace": true,
           "conservativeCollapse": true,
           "preserveLineBreaks": true,
           "caseSensitive": true,
           "minifyCSS": true
       },
   ```
2. HtmlWebpackPlugin

   ```
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     "template": "./src\\index.ejs",
     "filename": "./index.html",
     "hash": true,
     "inject": true,
     "compile": true,
     "favicon": 'src/assets/Flag.png',
     "minify": {
         collapseWhitespace: true,
         removeComments: true,
         minifyCSS: true
       },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this count as an answer because it's not really related to angular-cli, but I open my project in sublime text, and I launch [UnusedCssFinder](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/UnusedCssFinder), which highlight all the unused properties in my css file.

Answer (score -1):

In Angular the best option you have is to create a separate CSS file for each component and use ViewEncapsulated.Emulated.

And in this file you will add just CSS used by this component. You can discover styles used by each page with "coverge" from [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage)