# Does using @import more than once duplicate css?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, scss-mixins

I have an Angular CLI app and I'm using `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` in the global `styles.scss`. I also have a component where I would like to define a css class in that component's .scss file that uses some of the Angular Material typography:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$config: mat-typography-config();

.myClass {
  font-size: mat-font-size($config, title);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

By importing `~@angular/material/theming` more than once in my application, will it include that css more than once and bloat my payload? Or is the Angular CLI compiler smart enough to handle this?

Comment: "Angular CSS compiler" - the purging would be done by another component. The conductor for all the transformations in Angular CLI is, I believe, Webpack, but the latest versions of Angular hide its config from you. You likely want to include [this](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss) or its predecessor, and I don't think it is included by default. It's a pretty pickle. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/issues/96). Possible duplicate: [Can angular-cli remove unused css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330938/can-angular-cli-remove-unused-css)

Comment: @Amadan, so my question was if `@import` will duplicate the code. Are saying that it will since you're suggesting the use of a utility that will remove duplicate code? Either way, I don't think it's a duplicate question since I never asked how to remove duplicate css, only if it would be duplicated in the first place.

Comment: Yes. Also, see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8431). (As for not being a duplicate, look at it this way: if I see someone giving a class about how not to get eaten by hungry bears in winter, I don't think I need to ask if bears are dangerous :P )

Answer (score 2):

If you're importing the same CSS into multiple components, then *yes* the CSS will be duplicated, but each time it will be scoped to that component.

For example if you have the following...

product-list.component.css:

```
@import '../../foo.css';
...
```

top-bar.component.css:

```
@import '../../foo.css';
...
```

../../foo.css:

```
a { color: red; }
```

Your css output in the  tag will look something like this:

```
<style>
   a[_ngcontent-gna-c48] { color: red; }
   ...
</style>

<style>
   a[_ngcontent-gna-c50] { color: red; }
   ...
</style>
```

[Here's a full StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hced4r-j4junr) based on Angular's [Getting Started example project](https://angular.io/start).