# Remove Unused CSS on Angular 9 build process

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I have an Angular 9 project which I added [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) on *angular.json > projects.projectName.architect.build.options.styles* so it bundles up the framework on styles.css. The thing is that checking the coverage in Chrome I find this:

[image: unused css coverage]

I tried PurgeCSS and PurifyCSS on their own, working on the "dist" folder and also integrating it using [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) but without luck.

Also tried: [Angular 8/Sass: Find unused css classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878222/angular-8-sass-find-unused-css-classes?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Angular CLI Webpack by AngularRU](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-cli-webpack)

I'm trying to keep everything within Angular's build process avoiding *ng eject*.

How do you do when deploying an Angular App to Production? Because I'm pretty sure I'm not the first that comes up with this problem.

Thank you in advance for any clue you can give me to solve this issue.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use **PurgeCSS**

PurceCSS is a well-known tool that scans the output of the built CSS files and will use it's heuristics and extractors to remove unused CSS - predominantly brought to fame thanks to Tailwind.

Refer below link for your reference.

https://dev.to/dylanvdmerwe/reduce-angular-style-size-using-purgecss-to-remove-unused-styles-3b2k